# Collecting Srapy Selectors href

Tags: css, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get all the href values of the attribute "a" of class "boatAd__image--withInnerImg js-targetBlank" from this [website](https://www.clickandboat.com/en/boat-rental/search?where=Dubrovnik&TypeNavigation=Without%20captain&ProduitTypeId=Catamaran;Sailboat&LongueurMin=10&LongueurMax=15&NbCabinesMin=3&_page=8&_nbKm=100&_tri=Selection&hasDiscount=0) only the first page needed.

To start with, I tried doing so with scrapy using **.css**:

```
for row in response.css("a.boatAd__image--withInnerImg.js-targetBlank"):
    print(row)
```

but it is not printing anything.

I tried also using **.xpath** :

```
x = response.xpath('//a[@class="boatAd__image--withInnerImg.js-targetBlank"]/@href')
print(x)
```

but it is not displaying anything either.

I am new with scrapy and selectors so it might be a small mistake from me... The class of the attribute "a" contains a space so I put a dot instead (I read it was what we had to do).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The page uses javascript, so the html your browser shows won't necessarily be the same as `scrapy` sees. See [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html) for how to work around that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I looked at the website you suggested. With the website I have it says I should use selectors but it is what I am doing so I do not understand how I can manage to get the urls for my website ...

Comment: Did you inspect the source code of the webpage as that page suggests? Or try opening the webpage in the browser with javascript disabled? You'll see that what you are looking for doesn't exist...

Comment: Yes I tried. The page is not generated using JavaScript because when I disable javascript and reload the page the content is still there. But when I click on the boat pictures I am not being directed to the boat's page. So it means that it generates javascript only for the link of the website for each particular boats?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: So how can I manage this ?

Comment: Using one of the methods discussed on the page I linked in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing up xpath and css syntax. Try `//a[@class="boatAd__image--withInnerImg js-targetBlank"]/@href` with the space, or `//a[contains(@class, "boatAd__image--withInnerImg")]/@href`

Comment: Thank you for your comment however, your first solution is rendering an empty array and the second solution is not rendering anything...

Comment: I had a quotation mark out of place on the second one. I've corrected it and it may work now.

Comment: Thanks for the update but still not working .... I think the problem is because this specific a attribute with the href are generated dynamically and not static ... so scrapy does not see this part when reading the HTML. Do you know how I can still get the href value when they are generated automatically ?

Comment: I was able to confirm you are correct by writing `response.text` to a file and examining what scrapy sees. I'm afraid the href values you want are not contained in the response at all. If you can, I would suggest using Selenium for a different approach. If not, it's going to take more work to figure out where those urls are coming from.